# Calling a function from if block in success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Hello fellow programmers. I am newbie to jquery ajax.
How do i call function checkreturn() from if block  or is it possible to access msg outside the success if yes then please let me know how. I need it because only if condition proves true i have to enable the subsequent textbox. Here is my code.Thanks in advance for your time and reply.Rajesh.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    

        function checkreturn()        {   

            document.getElementById("txtAns").removeAtrribute("disabled");                     
        }
        function cQtn(e){             
        var uname= $("#<%=Username.ClientID%>").val();
        var sq=$("#<%=SecQuest.ClientID%>");
        var sqtn = $("#<%=SecQuest.ClientID%> option:selected").text();
        var sans=$("#txtAns");      
        var msgbox = $("#Dstatus");
          $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",                    
                    url: "forgotpassword.aspx/CheckValidSQtn",
                    data: "{'uname':'"+uname+"','args':'"+sqtn+"'}", 
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {                                                                                                             
                         if (msg.d == 'Available') {                            
                            sq.removeClass("notavailablecss");
                            sq.addClass("availablecss");
                            msgbox.html('<img src="proj_mages/a.png"> <font color="Green"> Valid </font>');
                            //how do i call from here??                                                                                                              
                           }
                        else {                            
                            sq.removeClass("availablecss");
                            sq.addClass("notavailablecss");
                            msgbox.html(msg.d);                           
                        }                        
                    }                                                 
                });                                     
      }     

    </script>
```

Comment: Same way you'd call it anywhere else? `checkTurn();`

Comment: checkreturn() in this case, but yes.

Comment: It is not getting called.I tried it. Is there a way i can enable the textbox control in the if block itself?

Comment: Where did you place the call to `checkreturn()` when you tried it? Could you post that code, maybe it was in the wrong place or maybe no success was returned?

Comment: I placed the call in exactly same place where i have put the comment..//how do i call from here?

Comment: if you placed the call to `checkreturn` inside of the `if` statement, where your comment is, and it didn't get called, then my guess is that `msg.d == 'Available'` evaluated to `false`. Right before the `if` statement, do a `console.log(msg)` and see what values you are getting back from the server.

Comment: Thank you guys its quite helping. as @lbstr pointed out its evaluating to false. I was a bit frustrated and just blindly ignored that point. Thank you once again for all help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your `checkreturn` function. You want to use `removeAttribute`, instead of `removeAtrribute` (double `t`,not double `r`).

Also, you can use `jQuery` functions:

```
function checkreturn(){   
    $('#txtAns').prop('disabled',false);                
}
```

, instead of native `DOM` functions (`document.getElementById`, `setAttribute`):

Answer (score 0):

not sure what why the normal way is not working but you could try forcing what the browser is supposed to do,

```
function checkreturn(){   
     document.getElementById("txtAns").removeAtrribute("disabled");                     
}
```

Becomes

```
window.checkreturn = function(){   
     document.getElementById("txtAns").removeAtrribute("disabled");                     
}
```

Then try calling via `window.checkreturn();` or `checkreturn();` you can also so try this the other way arround so you can leave your function and try calling `window.checkreturn();`

If none of these are working it would say your function is not entering the window(Global) scope for your page use Firebug or Inspector and try to all `checkreturn();` see what exception you get back,

if you get a not found your not showing us some thing in your code maybe a closure or some thing

Answer (score -1):

I'll look into it further but try setting `async` for the `ajax` call to `false`:

```js
function checkreturn() {

    document.getElementById("txtAns").removeAtrribute("disabled");

}

function cQtn(e) {

    var uname= $("#<%=Username.ClientID%>").val(),
        sq=$("#<%=SecQuest.ClientID%>"),
        sqtn = $("#<%=SecQuest.ClientID%> option:selected").text(),
        sans=$("#txtAns"),
        msgbox = $("#Dstatus");

    $.ajax( {
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "forgotpassword.aspx/CheckValidSQtn",
        data: "{'uname':'"+uname+"','args':'"+sqtn+"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.d == 'Available') {
                sq.removeClass("notavailablecss");
                sq.addClass("availablecss");
                msgbox.html('<img src="proj_mages/a.png"> <font color="Green"> Valid </font>');
                //how do i call from here??
            } else {
                sq.removeClass("availablecss");
                sq.addClass("notavailablecss");
                msgbox.html(msg.d);
            }
        }
    } );

}
```

Now, when the `ajax` call is made, the rest of the script will wait til it completes instead of how everything continues when `async` is `true`.